# Событие click и scroll не отрабатывают

Tags: jquery, css, анимация

Доброго времени суток. Моя проблема состоит в том, что не срабатывает повторно событие `click`.

Допустим у меня поверх гугл карт есть картинка фоновая. По клику на неё я делаю ей `opacity` в ноль, с `.animate` в 2 секунды и прячу картинку `.hide`.
По скролу возвращаю `opacity` в единицу и показываю картинку `.show`.
Если кликнуть опять по картинке, то повторный клик не отрабатывает, бывает, что отрабатывает через 5-10 секунд после клика.

https://jsfiddle.net/yhzqzafc/

Менял событие `scroll` на `mouseleave` - все отлично работает, повторные клики отрабатывают. Но нужно именно с скролом.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Решено. По клику делаем .fadeOut(1000), по скролу делаем .fadeIn(1000) на элементе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем всё просто. Я перемудрил.
По клику делаем `.fadeOut(1000)`,
по скролу делаем `.fadeIn(1000)` на элементе

Answer (score 1):

Добавил через `else` условие где картинка появляеться,

```js
 $(function() {
  $('.image').click(function() {
var opacity = $(this).css("opacity");
if (opacity === "0") {
  $('.image').animate({
    opacity: "1",
  }, 2000);
  
} else{
 $('.image').animate({
    opacity: "0",
  }, 2000);
}
  });
  $(window).scroll(function() {

var opacity = $('.image').css("opacity");

if (opacity === "0") {
  $('.image').show(1000);
  $('.image').animate({
    opacity: "1",
  }, 1000);

}
  });
});

$(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {

var opacity = $('.image').css("opacity");

if (opacity === "0") {
  $('.image').show(1000);
  $('.image').animate({
    opacity: "1",
  }, 1000);

}
  });
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  height: 1200px;
}

p {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.image {
  widht: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <p>
    <img src="http://jasonhumphrey.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/jsfiddle.png" class="image">
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, так работает. Но мне нужно после того как картинка станет прозрачной, дать ей display: none; Потому, что у меня под ней гугл карты, если не задать ей этот параметр, я не смогу скролить карту. Поэтому я и делал по клику `opacity` + `hide`. Ну и по скролу наоборот. И если делать моим способом, то второй раз событие по клику не проходит.